# collapse only the 1st column of dataframe in R with remaining columns data intact

Tags: r, dataframe, kable, kableextra

I am new to R and I have a dataframe like below

```
    
Gender Not_Hired Division Hired Total %Hired Odds
Male    490        F       31   521   6.0   0.063
Male    193        E       74   267   27.7  0.383
Male    389        D      193   582   33.2  0.496
Male    286        C      167   453   36.9  0.584
Male    289        B      493   782   63.0  1.706
Male    437        A      715   1152  62.1  1.636
Female  442        F      33    475   6.9   0.075
Female  417        E      131   548   23.9  0.314
Female  341        D      183   524   34.9  0.537
Female  546        C      282   828   34.1  0.516
Female  11         B      24    35    68.6  2.182
Female  27         A      124   151   82.1  4.593
```

And I am looking for an output like
[image: Output]

I tried below code

```
output %>% 
   select(Division, everything()) %>%
   group_by(Division) %>% ungroup() %>%
  kbl(caption = 'Company wide hiring',
      col.names = c('','','Hired','Not Hired','Total','%Hired','Odds(Hired)'),
      digits = 3) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

And getting below output:
[image: My Output]

How do I get from my output to desired output. Any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to use `collapse_rows` on the first column. However, to prepare the data for `kable` output, would make sure to have `Division` and `Gender` as the first two columns, and use `arrange` by `Division` so the rows with common `Division` are next to each other.

```
library(magrittr)
library(kableExtra)

df %>%
  select(Division, Gender, everything()) %>%
  arrange(Division) %>%
  kbl(caption = 'Company wide hiring',
      col.names = c('','','Hired','Not Hired','Total','%Hired','Odds(Hired)'),
      digits = 3) %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1)
```

**Output**

[image: table with collapse_rows on first column]